# Unit Testing COM Object from NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, com-interop

I'm creating a COM object library in C#, so instead of doing what I normally do and making a reference to said project then calling the object directly I want to call it using COM interop. I've done some COM interop before, but I'm not 100% that what I did before applies to what I want to accomplish here. So here is what I am trying in NUnit (and thus far it is working, but i'm not 100% that it is a valid test)

```
[Guid("75A39482-132D-4F98-A248-69BFB0EE9DEA"),
ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IBPBarcodeDevice))]
public class TestBPBarcode : IBPBarcodeDevice
{
    public Data.BarcodeData GetBarcodeData()
    {
        return new Data.BarcodeData(Constants.BARCODE_SYMBOLOGY.BARCODE_AZTEK, new byte[] { 0x48, 0x65, 0x6C, 0x6C, 0x6F, 0x20, 0x57, 0x6F, 0x72, 0x6C, 0x64});
    }

    public bool HasBarcodeData()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void EnableBarcodeScanner()
    {
        GetBarcodeEnabled = true;

    }
    public bool GetBarcodeEnabled { get; set; }
    public void DisableBarcodeScaner()
    {
        GetBarcodeEnabled = false;
    }

    public event BarcodeDataReceivedHandler BarcodeDataReceived;
    private void FireBarcodeDataReceived()
    {
        Console.Beep(2000, 500);
        if (BarcodeDataReceived != null)
            BarcodeDataReceived(this);
    }
    void Interfaces.IBarcodeEvents.BarcodeDataReceived(Interfaces.IBPBarcodeDevice device)
    {
        Console.Beep(1000, 200);
        if(BarcodeDataReceived != null)
            BarcodeDataReceived(device);
    }
```

**UnitTest**

```
public class TestSandBox : AssertionHelper
{
    [Test]
    public void TestNunitIsInstalledProperly()
    {
        Expect(true, "NUnit must be setup properly for this test of true==true to pass");
    }

    [Test]
    public void CanInstantiateBPBarcodeThroughCOM()
    {
        string testBarcode = "BPOS.SDK.Interfaces.TestBPBarcode";

        dynamic barcodeDevice = CreateCOMObject(testBarcode);
        Expect(barcodeDevice.HasBarcodeData() == true);
    }

    private static dynamic CreateCOMObject(string objectName)
    {
        return Activator.CreateComInstanceFrom("UnitTests.dll", objectName).Unwrap();
    }
}
```

ok so is this a valid way of testing if my object is going to work as a COM Object?
And as a side note.. extra credit.. how can I fire that event in my TestBPBarcode?